# Can I have both a code-behind Click event as well as a Command?

Tags: wpf

I'd like to know if I can have both a button click event in the code-behind, as well as a command in the viewmodel, and they both work? Like this:

```
<Button x:Name="CancelButton"
        Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"
        Content="Cancel" Click="CancelButton_Click" />
```

Comment: Did you try it? What was the result?

Comment: `Command` and the `Click` event have nothing to do with MVVM light.

Comment: Yes sure... in `MVVM` you are still allowed to use code behind for the `View` part only... But if you could explain what you exactly want to accomplish, I am pretty sure there are no needs for that. The `UI` part should be done with triggers and styles instead

Comment: mason, yes I've tried it and it works. OmegaMan (sorry, don't know how to put the Greek letter Omega in my reply), sorry to confusing the command with MVVM Light. I mentioned MVVM Light only if it might help others in responding. Newed Nabi Zada, I'm under a time constraint to get this done for a presentation. I would rather use MVVM Light's messaging in order to signal the window to close itself, but because I've other things to prepare for the presentation, doing what I've done with the Click event and the Command will suffice, for now.

Comment: Because I hadn't tried it before asking. Moreover, if it did work once, I wasn't sure if that might have simply been a fluke of the click event and the command just happening to execute as I hoped it would. My thinking was that it still might go wrong; I may only have been lucky the time I tested it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can. The `Click` event handler will be invoked and executed before the `Execute` method of the command.

Note that implementing any application logic in the `Click` event handler in the view effectively breaks the MVVM pattern though.